# Missing required parameter: redirect_uri in spotify clone app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

idk why i keep getting this error "Missing required parameter: redirect_uri" while trying to clone the web spotify application.

## code:

```
// https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/#

export const authEndpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
const redirectURI= "http://localhost:3000";

const clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

const scopes = [
    "user-read-currently-playing",
    "user-read-recently-played",
    "user-read-playback-state",
    "user-top-read",
    "user-modify-playback-state",
];

export const loginUrl= `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}&scope=${scopes.join(
    "%20"
  )}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`;
```

i already checked the last line multiple times and tried to change the endpoint. didn't help.

Comment: Used your code and try into the browser at first it gave me error `invalid redirect uri` So I remove the `http://` from the redirectURI and works without any issue

Comment: omg it actually worked, thank you... but how? why? like, why would it work only without the http:// ? i mean if you dont know the answer thats fine, but that got me curious. and thanks again btw, helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, it seems that you have defined the redirectURI variable correctly as "http://localhost:3000". However, the error could be occurring due to a mismatch between the redirect_uri value specified in your Spotify developer dashboard and the one you are using in the code.

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer, but i think thats not the issue, i already checked the dashboard because of that possibility. would u have any other idea?